# How to sort a collection by the difference of two fields?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In my collection, each document has two values that look like this:

```
{
  originalPrice: 500,
  ourPrice: 420
}
```

As you can imagine, I'd like the users to be able to sort by how much they will save shopping from us rather than from a competitor, which for this particular good is 80.

However, this value is itself not in the database, so I can't simply do

```
Goods.find({}, {sort: saveAmount: 1})
```

or anything like that.

It would perhaps be an easy task to insert this number in the database, but unless the approach to get things working the other way is extremely complicated I'd prefer not to.

So I want a function that does this,

```
var saveAmount = function(originalPrice, ourPrice) {
  return originalPrice - ourPrice
}
```

and somehow use this value to sort by!

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you looked into using an [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)?

Comment: @JasonCust Nope, first time I hear about it!

Comment: Have you tried [Map-reduction](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) ?

Comment: check aggregation framework on mongodb

Comment: @Yeats give it a shot and if you get stuck post back here. Mongoose supports it with the [`aggregate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) method. Good luck!

Comment: Information overload :)

Comment: Found this in the Meteor docs: "In this release, Minimongo has some limitations:

$pull in modifiers can only accept certain kinds of selectors.
findAndModify, aggregate functions, and map/reduce aren't supported."

Comment: Are the documents you need to sort already on the client, or do you need to sort as part of the publish function?

Comment: @DavidWeldon Don't really know what you mean with "already on the client". This is a regular publication/subscription.

Comment: I mean, do you need to know the difference in price in order to decide which  `Goods` documents should be published? E.g. "only publish the top 50 goods by price difference".

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a MongoDB query, but not with meteor. So you'll have to use a separate field as you proposed. Here's what you can do:

```
function setDifference (doc) {
  var difference = doc.originalPrice - doc.ourPrice
  Goods.update(doc._id, { $set: { difference: difference } })
}

Goods.find().observe({
  added: setDifference,
  updated: setDifference
})
```

If you are using simple-schema, you could use `autoValue`.

```
...
difference: {
  type: Number,
  autoValue: function () {
    return this.field('originalPrice').value - this.field('ourPrice').value
  }
}
...
```

Anyway, now you can just sort by `difference`:

```
Goods.find({}, {sort: {difference: -1}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you could display the goods in sorted order on the client:

**js**

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  sortedGoods: function() {
    return _.sortBy(Goods.find().fetch(), function(good) {
      return good.originalPrice - good.ourPrice;
    });
  }
});
```

**html**

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#each sortedGoods}}
    <div class="good">{{name}}: ${{ourPrice}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Don't really know how I'd use that helper! Also, I am using a `limit` in my publication in case that matters.

Comment: Yeah, this is a decent solution but it doesn't play very well together with a `limit` on the publication, for obvious reasons. The same thing would have to be done on the server.

Comment: That makes sense. This is what I was trying to get at in my questions above. If you need to know about the difference at the time of the publication then you should store it as a separate field. That's the only efficient solution.